# vRealize Automation - Software Component bind variable of second nic IP

Tags: automation, vmware-server

So i am having troubles with automating a deployment in vRA. I created a software component with 3 scripts and in one of the script i need to provide as a variable the Reserved/Alocated IP of the second nic (nic1) from the provisioned VM.

From what i searched online and in the documentation of the VM properties i can only extract the first IP from the first nic (nic0) . I can do this with the following sintax :

```
_resource~<VMcluster_name>~ip_address[<cluster machine no.>]
```

Do you know if it is possible to extract the IP of the second interface?

Thanks

Comment: Don't know the answer but how were you able to get the cluster machine number?

Comment: I just hardcoded as in my case had a fix cluster of 3 VM's. However, because of lack of dynamic provisioning i switched to python scripting using the vRA API's to extract the needed data and fed it to ansible  to configure the VM.